# How to hover a map nicely?

Tags: javascript, html, css, here-api

I've just started using `HERE API` and there's a little issue.
The map I add to my HTML document works fine. The problems appears when I try to use hover in CSS. Instead of the map expending smoothly there's a big empty area in the right corner.
Here's my CSS:

```css
#mapContainer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#mapContainer {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#mapContainer:hover {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Below you can see my JS code:

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
   'apikey': {myApiKey}
});

var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
var map = new H.Map(
document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
{
    zoom: 10,
    center: { lng: 17.0, lat: 51.0 }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
    ui.getControl('zoom').setDisabled(false)

var icon = new H.map.Icon('img/marker.png', {size:{h:50,w:50}}); 
var markerWroclaw = new H.map.Marker({ lat: 51.0, lng: 17.0 }, { icon: icon });
map.addObject(markerWroclaw);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
        <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"  charset="utf-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >window.ENV_VARIABLE = 'https://developer.here.com'</script>
        <script src='https://developer.here.com/javascript/src/iframeheight.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="back_end/js/main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/indexstyle.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mapContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have the map code? Would be good if you can create a demo out of it.

Comment: I've just added the map code.